# Retrieve TTM previous quarter's sales

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to retrieve previous quarter's TTM(trailing 12 months) sales.

To retrieve current quarter's TTM sales, I can use `request.financial ("NASDAQ:AAPL", "TOTAL_REVENUE", "TTM")`

However, I am at a loss how to retrieve previous quarter's TTM sales.

From the documentation, it seems like only the latest quarter's financial info is available. I hope I am wrong.

https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000564727-what-financial-data-is-available-in-pine/

I am using pinescript v5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © moebius1977

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = false)
ttm = request.financial ("NASDAQ:AAPL", "TOTAL_REVENUE", "TTM")

// array to store all TTM values
var arTtm = array.new<float>()

// populate the array
if ta.change(ttm)
    arTtm.unshift(ttm)

// get the previous value if any
prevTtm  = if arTtm.size() <= 1 
    na
else
    arTtm.get(1)

plot(ttm, color = color.red)
plot(prevTtm, color = color.green)
```

Comment: Hi, I found this after some intense Googling and this does work. But I can not understand why it works. What is it with `if ta.change(ttm) arTtm.unshift(ttm)` that makes it work? From documentation array.unshift just adds a value to the beging of the array. ta.change says that it "Compares the current `source` value to its value `length` bars ago and returns the difference." Thanks!

Comment: If I remove the `if ta.change(ttm)` it does not work. So it seem like there is a side effect to that call that I can not understand from docuemtnation. It does not work like this either: 

`v = ta.change(ttm) 
arTtm.unshift(v)`